# slick return single result

Tags: scala, slick

this slick query works correctly:

```
val db = Database.forConfig("slick-mysql")
val query: SqlStreamingAction[Vector[Company], Company, Effect] = sql"""select * from company""".as[Company]
val futureResult: Future[Vector[Company]] = db.run(query)
```

However, how can I get a single row (`Future[Company]`)?

```
val id = 1
val query = sql"""select * from company where id=$id""".as[Company] // make it a single value (head or headOption)
val futureResult: Future[Company] = db.run(query)
```

I am aware that I could use `futureResult.map(_.headOption)`. But I wonder if slick allows to specify a single result (as i anorm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try calling `.headOption` on the db action itself like so

```
sql"""select * from company where id=$id""".as[Company].headOption
```

Now `db.run(query)` returns `Future[Option[Company]]`. Technically `.head` is also possible which would return `Future[Company]` however it is unsafe.

Consider writing queries [in Scala](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#querying) instead of [plain SQL](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/sql.html), for example, it should be possible to rewrite plain sql like so

```
 db.run {
    companies
      .filter(_.id === id)
      .take(1)
      .result
      .headOption
  }
```

where `companies` is [`TableQuery`](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/schemas.html#table-query).